# Media Queries: How to target all landscape devices below 1024 using css media query

Tags: html, css, media-queries

How to target all landscape devices below 1024 using css media query this should work only for mobile devices not desktop browsers

Answer (score 1):

You can try it like this

```
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1024px)
  and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 2.0)
  and (orientation: landscape) {

  //styles here

}
```

Comment: i want to target all mobile device landscape mode except ipads and desktop browsers

Comment: Check it now and follow up further here to target specific devices here https://www.studiopress.com/website-respond-mobile-devices/

Answer (score 0):

In below Media Query CSS will be affected to devices where maximum width is 1024px. That means devices where screen width is less than 1024px will be affected from this.

```
 @media screen and ( max-width :1024px) and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 2.0)
     and (orientation: landscape){
       .your_CSS_Class{

          //your styles

      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@media only screen 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (orientation: landscape) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

    //your styles

}
```